# App Crashes due to UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle when testing on phone but not emulator

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview with an array of dictionary values producing a fairly big list.
That the user can select from.. once the user selects a cell I pop the view from the navigational stack and pass all the values back to the main view.. I then allow the user to go back to this view if they have made a mistake and would like to change their input.

when they click back to that view I have a method that automatically scrolls to the old selected view using UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle.

However I think its causing some errors when being used on the phone, as the emulator works fine.

here is where I think the error is happening

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //Center previously selected cell to center of the screen
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedData  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES]; //<--- this method
}
```

and this is the error I get in the log when building it to my phone. The process in order to get this error is for the user to click on the cell in the parent view that loads the subview, the user selects a cell in the subview and is taken back to the parent view.. then when the user goes back to the same subview  this shows up in the log.

```
2011-10-19 15:00:05.790 icode[1564:707] -[__NSArrayM section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181cd0
2011-10-19 15:00:05.797 icode[1564:707] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[__NSArrayM section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181cd0
```

(there is no scroll effect)
then the user selects a different cell and this app crashes and this shows up in the log

```
2011-10-19 15:01:08.272 icode[1564:707] -[__NSArrayM row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181cd0
2011-10-19 15:01:08.275 icode[1564:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181cd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x35e9e8b3 0x366e61e5 0x35ea1acb 0x35ea0939 0x35dfb680 0x334a76cf 0x3353c713 0x30e1d 0x3352cd69 0x335a60ab 0x35cc32ab 0x35e72a57 0x35e726bd 0x35e71293 0x35df44e5 0x35df43ad 0x30fa4fed 0x334a7dc7 0x24f7 0x24a0)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tableview data sources

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [arraysByLetter count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *currentLetter = [sectionLetters objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[arraysByLetter objectForKey:currentLetter] count];
}

/*
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    //override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background colorset up shit here
}
 */

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } 

    //Customize cell here
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; // no blue selection

    //Replaces previously selected cells accessory view (tick)
    if (indexPath == oldCheckedData) 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } 

    //Display cells with data
    NSArray *keys = [self.arraysByLetter objectForKey:[self.sectionLetters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    return cell;
}

//Section headers
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [sectionLetters objectAtIndex:section];
}

//Section header titles
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionLetters;

}
```

Comment: Post your code that shows TableViewDataSource methods. From your logs, you are passing row and section methods to an Array object which crashes your app. Also when compiling your Source Code look at compiler warnings.

Comment: there are no warnings when it builds.. I have updated code with my TableViewDataSource methods

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the index path you have a reference to at `oldCheckedData` may have been deallocated when the view controller was popped from the stack. Make sure you retain it before the view controller goes away.

Comment: well in the emulator, oldCheckedData works fine. it scrolls to the correct top and assingment the tick on the correct indexpath.. so Im not sure if thats it... I have NSloged oldCheckedData also and it seems to be okay.

Comment: It is possible that `oldCheckedData` has been dealloced but still sitting at the memory location pointed to by a reference in the parent vc. In the simulator, you have a lot more memory to work with so it may not have been reused yet. Phone memory is a different story.

Comment: Try setting a break point at `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedData  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];` and see what `oldCheckedData` is when reloading the subview.